# How to store multiple images on server?

Tags: mysql, storing-data

Imagine that we have an e-shop. We need to store images connected with products somewhere on server. We already know, that it is better to store images in filesystem and keep the reference in DB.

The question is what is the best way to interconnect images in filesystem with product in DB:

I am thinking about:

1. keep the reference to unique folder dynamically created for this product in DB (f.e. directly in products table)
2. create new table in db (something like product_and_images) where we will keep information about product identification and image identification and table will serve for all products

Thanks for all of your answers and sorry for my terrible english :)

Comment: In my opinion you should have a 'ProductPictures' folder on the server, and Product table on your DB with a column named 'PicRef' which contains the file name with the file extention.But your should name the file as the product_id (1.png,2.jpg)

Comment: I suggest that if the images aren't large to store them base64 encoded (so regular SQL queries can still show them without garbling the output) if they are big, to save them as files

Comment: @Omer Eldan: But I need to store reference to multiple images for one product.

Comment: @BigT ohh i see. so one table is Products and the second is ProductPicture. name the pictures as ProductPictureID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always better to maintain separate table and use foreign key reference

Comment: So you mean that the option 2 is better approach?

Comment: Yes when you are using RDBMS it is always better to achieve normalization. Also using foreign key reference maintenance will be easier.

Comment: what about having a seperate table and another table for the realtion of the both including the ids from the both, dropping the foreign key reference in one to another. Is this idea better?